# why does my crash using addOnCompleteListener in if stament

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

I made this code, in which if addOnComplete doesnt work is because the email input already exists, but when I press the button the app close

```
.addOnCompleteListener {
                    if (!it.isSuccessful) {
                        // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                        Log.d("register", "Successfully created with uid: ${it.result?.user?.uid}")
                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(this, "the email already exists",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    }

                    val intent = Intent(this, Inicio::class.java)
                    startActivity(intent)
}
```

what im expecting is that if(correct) go to a new activity, else ask again for the email because they are entering a email that already exist (register page)

the app crashes when I press the button register

```
.addOnCompleteListener {
                    if (!it.isSuccessful) return@addOnCompleteListener
                        // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                        Log.d("register", "Successfully created with uid: ${it.result?.user?.uid}")
                    val intent = Intent(this, Inicio::class.java)
                    startActivity(intent)    
                }
```

doing it this way it works, but Im trying to show the message "email already exists", and using if else it crash

edit: after some testing the code works and it doesnt crash or it havent crash yet, the only problem now is that although the program goes to the new page the message "this email already exists appear" although this shouldnt accour because the if(correct) statatement have been done (move to the new page), firebase was empty (i cleaned all the emails already entered)

Edit2: trying to enter the same email (what i was trying to solve using the if statement made the app crash

2019-07-13 23:40:33.252 27529-27529/com.FestU E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.FestU, PID: 27529
    com.google.android.gms.tasks.RuntimeExecutionException: com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException: The email address is already in use by another account.
        at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzu.getResult(Unknown Source)
        at com.FestU.Register$onCreate$1$1.onComplete(Register.kt:42)
        at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzj.run(Unknown Source)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
     Caused by: com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException: The email address is already in use by another account.
        at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzdr.zzb(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzeu.zza(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzen.zzc(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzep.onFailure(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzdx.dispatchTransaction(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_auth.zza.onTransact(Unknown Source)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:573)

edit3: i figured out instead of else i used this

```
.addOnFailureListener {

                Log.d("main", "Failed to create user: ${it.message}")
                Toast.makeText(this, "El email ya existe o no es valido", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
```

Comment: Can you provide the stacktrace when the app closes? Also more lines of your code to give better context.

Comment: E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Comment: Update the question and include the full stack trace please. Adding as a comment won't work too well since it will be a lot of text.

Comment: question updated